# Apache/MYSQL Problem

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, apache2

Basically,

I get this error in my scripts:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/login/includes/db.php on line 10

I have uncommented extension:mysql.so

I dont know why its not working, restarted everything aswell.

I am running on ubuntu 32 bit. Apache/MYSQL is installed with full permissions.

Here is my PHPInfo page:

```
System  Linux rabbits.org 2.6.18-194.3.1.el5.028stab069.6 #1 SMP Wed May 26 19:05:45 MSD 2010 i686
Build Date  Jan 6 2010 21:40:40
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini
PHP API     20041225
PHP Extension   20060613
Zend Extension  220060519
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  zip, php, file, data, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, compress.zlib, https, ftps
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters   string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, convert.iconv.*, bzip2.*, zlib.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mysql was being properly loaded, you'd have seen something like:

```
additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini,
   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini
```

If the mysql.ini (or mysqli.ini) line isn't there, it's not being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the mysql extension in the phpinfo() output.

Comment: Thats not the whole PHP.ini file.

Comment: I uncommented: extension=mysql.so It was "extension=msql.so" before. I then restarted apache and still same problem.

Comment: Weird I used "apt-get install php5-mysql" and restarted the apache it worked.

Comment: Seems like you had apache, mysql, some apache-mysql-communication, but no php mysql connection